# Change argv[0] when exec'ing a python script

Tags: python, process, exec, argv

I have two python scripts, foo.py and bar.py

foo.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
os.execv('./bar.py', sys.argv)
```

bar.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print(sys.argv)
```

When I invoke `foo.py` I get the output

```
['./bar.py']
```

instead of

```
['./foo.py']
```

because the python interpreter is spawned from the shebang and sets `argv[0]` to `bar.py`, but I want to preserve the name of the original script in `argv[0]`.

Is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: Do you really need to call the separate file as a subprocess? Could you just import it, or use `execfile()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you obtain the OS's argv\[0\] (not sys.argv\[0\]) in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867761/how-can-you-obtain-the-oss-argv0-not-sys-argv0-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Roseman noted, `execfile` seems to do exactly what I wanted.

Sorry for apparently not doing enough research on this

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment rather than as an answer.